# VLOOKUP from a specific closed file doesn't fetch data

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I'm trying to Vlookup from a closed excel file called Bank.xlsx, but it always fails to get data

Below is my code, what possibly is done wrong?

```
Sub PrepareForPayment()
    
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim wbThis As Workbook
    Dim wsThis As Worksheet
         
    Set wbThis = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsThis = ActiveSheet

 MyPath = "C:\1.Martin\18.SAP\Bank Test"
    
 wsThis.Range("AA2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP('" & wsThis.Name & "'!D2,'" & MyPath & '[Bank.xlsx]Sheet1'!A:C,3,0)"
     
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: `MyPath & "\[Bank.xlsx]Sheet1'!A:C,3,0)"` try this

Answer (score 1):

I tried replicating it and this seems to work for me.

```
Sub PrepareForPayment()
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim wbThis As Workbook
    Dim wsThis As Worksheet
    
    Set wbThis = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsThis = ActiveSheet

    MyPath = "C:\1.Martin\18.SAP\Bank Test"
    wsThis.Range("AA2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(D2,'" & MyPath & "[Bank.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A:$C,3,0)"
End Sub
```

I did not include the **wsThis.Name** , Since it is just going to call the Sheet number and assuming on the part **Set wsThis = ActiveSheet** ,
It also refers to the active sheet which is your sheet number. you can just indicate the Cell **D2** directly since you are working on the same Sheet.